# How to disable PageViewController when scroll a table?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I am making an application in which I have used PageViewController and on every page a table is present. When I move page left and right then page is reflect but when I scroll a table upside then PageViewController also call the left page automatically and it is not true. So I want that when I scroll table then PageVieController must be not called. So can you suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done your setting **page view** scrolling correctly? If you provide the code then it will be easy to understand.